# QGIS + GRASS: r.in.gdal "View output" produces "cellhd file (...) does not exist"

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm working with a recently installed QGIS (2.10.1) + GRASS (6 v2.0) package, and have been working with some rasters and vectors in QGIS that I'd now like to play with using the GRASS tools.

I've set up my GRASS location, mapset etc, and made sure the region and projection are all correct - no issues there. I've then used r.in.gdal.qgis to load a raster from my QGIS environment, and that's proceeded without giving me any errors. However, nothing appears on the screen after that command is completed, and when I click "View output" I get an "Invalid Layer" error. The message I'm getting (with some URI parts removed) is as follows:

GRASS provider: cellhd file D:...\GRASS/Hopefield_GRASS/Hopefield_GRASS/cellhd/aster_GRASS does not exist

Raster layer: Provider is not valid (provider: grassraster, URI: D:...\GRASS/Hopefield_GRASS/Hopefield_GRASS/cellhd/aster_GRASS

I'm thinking maybe there's an issue with the path having both forward and backward slashes in it - perhaps that's getting GRASS confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more Googling, I came across a solution to a different problem that has also solved this problem. The simple fix was to locate the GRASS database and mapset in a different folder which did not contain any spaces in the name.