# QGIS and GRASS: r.in.gdal "View output" produces "Unavailable layer! Layer data source could not be found"

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, grass-gis

I'm quite new to QGIS and I'm working with QGIS 3.22.2-Bialowieza and GRASS 7 package, I use macOS Monterey 12.  I have a few vectors and rasters I need to transform to GRASS format in order to construct least cost paths. CRS are the same for all vectors and layers.

I need to use r.in.gdal.qgis to import my raster layer into a GRASS format (my raster is a Digital elevation model DEM). The process works fine, takes some time and it ends with no errors stating "Successfully finished". However, nothing appears on the screen and when I click on "view output" an empty layer appears with error sign: "Unavailable layer! Layer data source could not be found"

My original source URI (with some parts removed) is /Users/(...)/Documents/QGIS/GRASS/GRASS/Mapset/cellhd/DEMITGRASS

It must be some issue with the path but I can't tell what it is. I already saw this past thread [QGIS + GRASS: r.in.gdal "View output" produces "cellhd file (...) does not exist"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157968/qgis-grass-r-in-gdal-view-output-produces-cellhd-file-does-not-exist) which seems to have an identical problem to mine and simply suggests to locate the GRASS database and mapset in a different folder which does not contain any spaces in the name. However, that does not work for me as my path does not contain any spaces.

I also tried downloading a different DEM raster from a different source and I still get the same error, thus the problem is not with the raster itself.

N.B. the subfolder "cellhd" only contains small files of a few KBs, the heavy files are in another subfolder of the GRASS folder called "fcell" (all files do not end in .tif but are of the kind "Document"). I don't fully understand the differences between the folders but I cannot change the path to "fcell"

Comment: What do you try to achieve? The GRASS GIS raster format is distinct from GeoTIFF. To compute least cost paths simply open the raster map of interest in QGIS, then run the r.cost command on it. This will internally call `r.in.gdal`.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it works. I was using this guide https://bit.ly/348MMvH which suggested doing all steps via the "GRASS tools" screen after opening a GRASS mapset. If I simply use the same GRASS tools via the "Processing Toolbox" screen I don't get the same issue as r.in.gdal is internally called, as you suggested.