# QGIS Grass Raster import using r.in.gdal.qgis: 'Layer data source could not be found'

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin, data-source

I'm a QGIS learner following the official QGIS Training Manual. I'm on [Module 12.1](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/grass/grass_setup.html). My problem is that when I try to add a raster layer to GRASS using r.in.gdal.qgis, the resulting layer shows a red exclamation mark with this message:

> 'Unavailable layer! Layer data source could not be found. Click to set a new data source'

Under the 'information' layer properties, the 'source' is given as :

> '[...]/Documents/QGIS/GIS_Tutorials/QGIS_Official_Course/exercise_data/grass/grassdata/SouthAfrica/grass_mapset/cellhd/g_dem'.

which is the correct path for the maps, although I do not see the 'cellhd' anywhere. However, using 'Repair data source' to manually select the layer from the grass_dataset results in the same file path being listed under source, including the 'cellhd'.

[Another, quite old, question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157968/qgis-grass-r-in-gdal-view-output-produces-cellhd-file-does-not-exist) on this topic indicated that removing spaces from the path solved this, but I have tried this and the problem persists. What reasons might there be why the source cannot be found, and how can I fix it?

QGIS Version: 3.26.3-Buenos Aires

GRASS Version: 7.8.6RC2 (2021)

OS: Mac OS Monterrey 12.4

Comment: On a sidenote, GRASS GIS 7.8 is pretty old. To your question (I didn't check the tutorial yet): `grass_mapset/cellhd/g_dem` indicate that the data are already in the GRASS GIS raster format, so no real need to import them (that would be kind of circular...).

Comment: @markusN thanks for your comment. it's correct that g_dem is the name of the layer created by r.in.gdal.qgis, so it makes sense that it is in GRASS raster format. The issue is that this layer does not show up on the canvas when loaded, and shows the error 'Unavailable layer! Layer data source could not be found. Click to set a new data source' mentioned above.